# How to modify Python EnumType to allow subclassing an enum with members?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to subclass an Enum with members for simplicity in my project. I'd like to modify the EnumMeta type to allow for subclassing. I know this has to be possible but I cannot wrap my head around metaclasses to save my life.

Are there any suggestions I can try to modify EnumMeta to remove the subclass restriction?

Answer (score 0):

Ok this was easy.

```
class SubclassableEnumMeta(EnumMeta):
    @classmethod
    def _check_for_existing_members_(mcls, class_name, bases):
        ...


class SubclassableEnum(Enum, metaclass=SubclassableEnumMeta):
    ...
```

Edit:

You should also update `__new__` so the member map is updated:

```
class SubclassableEnumMeta(EnumMeta):
    @classmethod
    def _check_for_existing_members_(mcls, class_name, bases):
        ...

    def __new__(
        metacls: type[SubclassableEnumMeta],
        cls: str,
        bases: tuple[type, ...],
        classdict: _EnumDict,
        *,
        boundary: FlagBoundary | None = None,
        _simple: bool = False,
        **kwds: Any,
    ) -> SubclassableEnumMeta:
        enum = super().__new__(
            metacls,
            cls,
            bases,
            classdict,
            boundary=boundary,
            _simple=_simple,
            **kwds,
        )

        enum._member_map_.update(enum.__mro__[1]._member_map_)
        enum._member_names_ += enum.__mro__[1]._member_names_
        enum._value2member_map_.update(enum.__mro__[1]._value2member_map_)

        return enum
```

Final update to ensure unique members:

```
class SubclassableEnumMeta(EnumMeta):
    @classmethod
    def _check_for_existing_members_(mcls, class_name, bases):
        ...

    def __new__(
        metacls: type[SubclassableEnumMeta],
        cls: str,
        bases: tuple[type, ...],
        classdict: _EnumDict,
        *,
        boundary: FlagBoundary | None = None,
        _simple: bool = False,
        **kwds: Any,
    ) -> SubclassableEnumMeta:
        enum = super().__new__(
            metacls,
            cls,
            bases,
            classdict,
            boundary=boundary,
            _simple=_simple,
            **kwds,
        )

        if any(name in enum.__mro__[1]._member_names_ for name in enum._member_names_):
            raise TypeError("Enum members must be unique through inheritance.")

        enum._member_map_.update(enum.__mro__[1]._member_map_)
        enum._member_names_ += enum.__mro__[1]._member_names_
        enum._value2member_map_.update(enum.__mro__[1]._value2member_map_)

        return enum
```